# Check if a pair of keys already have a value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a file with the name, scores and exam number (in that order) of many students and want to know in which exam each student did best (scale from 1 to 5, 1 is the best score.) Some students might have taken only one exam, some took two. The files look like this:

```
student1,4.2,1
student2,1.02,1
student3,4.1,1
student4,2.089,1
student2,3.02,2
student3,2.54,2
student4,3.69,2
student5,1.34,2
```

I planed to create a dictionary with names, exam number, and scores and then retrieve the best score. My code looks like this:

```
with open('filename.csv') as f:
lines = f.readlines()

scores = {} #{ Name : { Exam_Number : score }

for line in lines:
   n = re.match(r"(.*)\,(.*)\,(.*)",line)
   student = n.group(1)
   score = n.group(2)
   exam_number = n.group.(3)
   scores[name] = { exam_number : score } #HERE IS THE PROBABLE ERROR

#Obtain the best score per student and the number of the exam
best_exam = {}
for name in scores:
    for num in scores[name]:
        for score in scores[name][num]:
             if name in best_sco:
                 for num_ext in best_sco[name]:
                      if best_sco[name][num] > num_ext:
                            best_sco[sample] = { num : amb }
                      else:
                            best_sco[name] = {num : amb }
```

I realized that whenever I try to include a new exam_number : score combination for an already  existing name, the previous pair stored for that particular name is erased. For instance, if I call the score for the student4, only the one corresponding to exam 2 will appear since this was the last to be read and the previous was overwritten. Is there a way to declare a dictionary with paired keys and then iterate through all the possible pairs considering that some keys (but no pairs) might be repeated?

**EDIT ---------------------------**

The same question in a slightly different way (it may ring a bell to people conversant in Python and Perl). Is there an equivalent to [Perl's Multidimensional Hashes](http://perlmaven.com/multi-dimensional-hashes)in Python?

Comment: That nested for loops... there's gotta be a better way to do that.....

Comment: @MooingRawr I'm kind of new to Python and don't know all the tools...

Comment: look into `defaultdict` and `csv`

Comment: A good way to represent your data is `{ "<student-name>": [{ "<exam>":<score>}, ... ] }, then for each `student-name` key in the dictionary, iterate over the array of exams and pick the best score

Comment: Would you plz check my answer if the result is correct?

Comment: @sparkandshine I'm doing that ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is better to store the csv file as a list of lists. And then use `itertools.groupby` to group by `name`, filter out the row with the highest `score`. Here is the source code.

```
import csv
import collections
import itertools
import operator

# Read a csv file as a list of lists
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:        # name, scores and exam number 
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    lists = [[row[0], float(row[1]), int(row[2])] for row in reader]


# Obtain the best score per student and the number of the exam
for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(lists, key=operator.itemgetter(0)), key=operator.itemgetter(0)):
    best_score = max(list(g), key=lambda x: x[1])

    print(best_score)
    # Output
    '''
    ['student1', 4.2, 1]
    ['student2', 3.02, 2]
    ['student3', 4.1, 1]
    ['student4', 3.69, 2]
    ['student5', 1.34, 2]
    '''
```

---

**The previous answer:**

Use nested dictionaries by implementing perl's autovivification feature

```
class AutoVivification(dict):
    """Implementation of perl's autovivification feature."""
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return dict.__getitem__(self, item)
        except KeyError:
            value = self[item] = type(self)()
            return value​
```

Replace the line `scores[name] = { exam_number : score }` with,

```
d = AutoVivification()
d[name][exam_number] = score
```

Comment: There is something weird with your new solution. Print(best_score) returns just the last object in lists, i.e., ['student5', 1, 2].

Comment: Side note: When I simplified the code to post in SO, I changed the scores to int to make them shorter, but in my file they are float of different length. That might be cause of the error. I will change that in the question.

Comment: @j91, then change `int()` to `float()`. Please my updated answer.

Comment: @j91, how it would be possiable. Pay attention to the code indentation. I got the above result on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

you could use tuples as keys in the dict, so long as there wasnt going to be a duplicate student/exam combination

```
best_sco[('student-name', 'exam')] = 'score'
```

Comment: I already thought about this one, but how do you implement the second part of the script without trying all the possible combinations? Looping though all combinations is incredibly inefficient (Imagine just one student took exam2)

Answer (score 0):

```
if not scores[name]:
    scores[name] = {exam_number, score}
else:
    scores[name][exam_number] = score


best_exam = {}
for name, person_results in scores.iteritems():
    best_exam_number = None
    best_score = None
    for exam_number, score in person_results.iteritems():
        if score > best_score:
            best_exam_number = exam_number
    best_exam[name] = {best_exam_number, best_score}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use defaultdict`? put the scores in a list then retrieve the highest one? and you can use csv for reading the file itself which will save you having to regex

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter
import csv


with open('filename.csv') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    scores = defaultdict(list) #{ Name : { Exam_Number : score }
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    for line in reader:
        student, score, exam = line
        scores[student].append({"exam": exam, "score": score}) # assuming they can only take an exam once


    for student, exams in scores.items():
        best = sorted(exams, key=itemgetter("score"), reverse=True)[0]
        print student, best
```